# Resetting MySQL's Temp Password

Tags: mysql, passwords

I'm trying to reset my MySQL temp password through terminal on MACOSX 10.11 using this tutorial (http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/)  but I get the error:

mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. 
Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.

How do I use an SSL connection to change the password?

Comment: why are you worried? unless the mysql server is offsite and your link is subject to sniffing by the NSA, it's all local traffic. unless your machine is TOTALLY compromised, there's no one there to sniff the data.

Comment: I'm not exactly worried but I can't seem to work around the error. It doesn't let me enter the new password.

Comment: Oh, wow. Okay, so it shows you the error but still takes the input. I didn't realize. Just tried logging in with the new password and it worked.

Comment: This is not an error message, only a warning.